# If $\Delta u \geq 0$, then $u$ attains its maximum in the boundary $\partial \Omega$

Tags: laplacian

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb R^n$ a bounded set and let $u \in C^2(\Omega) \cap C(\overline\Omega)$ be a real-valued function.

I need a hint to proof that if the laplacian $\Delta u \geq 0$, then $u$ attains its maximum in the boundary $\partial \Omega$.

Help?

Comment: This is answered in [Sign of Laplacian at critical points of $\mathbb R^n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/690122/sign-of-laplacian-at-critical-points-of-mathbb-rn/). If you just want a hint: if $a$ is an interior maximum point of $\Delta u$ then try to use the second derivative test for functions of one variable one variable at the time to show that $\Delta u \leq 0$ in this case.