# Sinks and Sources in Gradient Fields

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

Can you please critique my reasoning here? I know that there is a leap I am making that is incorrect, or I don't fully understand a critical piece.

I am looking at the Laplacian of $f(x,y)=2yx - xy^4$. I calculated $\Delta f(x,y) = -12xy^2$.

I am trying to interpret what this tells me about the function. I know that the Laplacian is just $\Delta f(x,y)=\nabla \cdot \nabla f(x,y)$ which is the divergence of $\nabla f(x,y)$.

Here is where I am struggling...points where the divergence is positive represent sources in the vector field, and points where the divergence is negative represent sinks in the vector field. Sinks in $\nabla f(x,y)$ correspond to local maximums of $f(x,y)$ while sources corresponds to local minimums.

My question is, there are infinitely many points where $-12xy^2$ is positive and infinitely many where $-12xy^2$ is negative, though I know these points are not all local extrema of $f(x,y)=2yx-xy^4$, so there are some inaccuracies in my logic above.

Am I even remotely interpreting the divergence relating to maximums and minimums correctly here? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The words "source" and "sink" are somewhat unfortunate in describing a phenomenon spread out over a region. When we have a flow field ${\bf v}$ then ${\rm div}\, {\bf v}({\bf p})>0$ means that for a small disk (in 2D) or ball (in 3D) centered at ${\bf p}$ there is more fluid flowing out per second on one side of this disk than is flowing in  on the other side of this disk. If this is true for ${\bf p}$ this is true for all points near ${\bf p}$. The reason could be that it rains in the neighborhood of ${\bf p}$ and that this additional amount of fluid has to flow away somehow in addition to the basic underground flow.

Note that local extrema ${\bf p}$ of some scalar function $f$ are signaled by $\nabla f({\bf p})={\bf 0}$, and not by the divergence of ${\bf v}:=\nabla f$ at ${\bf p}$ being positive, resp., negative.

Answer (score 1):

The Laplacian is just the trace of the [Hessian matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hessian_matrix) and not sufficient, in general, to get the local maxima and minima for a function. To accomplish this, you have to consider the entire Hessian matrix and  - what is more important - its determinant to apply the [second partial derivative test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_partial_derivative_test).

First of all, you need to determine the critical points for the function: the points where the gradient is zero. In this case the critical points are $(2y-y^4,2x-4xy^3)=(y(2-y^3),x(2-4y^3))$. Now, you have to compute the Hessian matrix:
$$
H(x,y)=\begin{pmatrix}f_{xx}(x,y)&f_{xy}(x,y)\\f_{yx}(x,y)&f_{yy}(x,y)\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0&2-4y^3\\2-4y^3&-12xy^2\end{pmatrix}. 
$$

Thus $\det(H)=-(2-4y^3)^2$, what means the determinant can be only negative or zero. We have to evaluate the determinant *only* for critical points, so the determinant cannot be zero because this would imply that the $x$ component of the gradient is not zero, thus not a critical point. Then all critical points for this function are saddle points.

Comment: I understand, thanks! Would it be correct to say that if $f$ has a local maximum at $(a,b)$ then $(a,b)$ is a sink of $\nabla f$, but the converse is not necessarily true?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. See this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/690122/sign-of-laplacian-at-critical-points-of-mathbb-rn/